# How to combine each inner observable (RxJs) with outer and emit one array?

Tags: angular, rxjs, expand

When I fire this code:

```
timer(1000).pipe(
  expand(() => of('a')),
  take(3)
)
  .subscribe(data => alert(data));
```

I get alert 3 times: alert with 0, alert with 'a', alert with 'a'.
I would like to get only one alert with, let's say, array [0, a, a].
How to combine all the values?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is interesting and (as Michael D notes in his answer) a very specific use case.

[An example of the following code, working in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tqwbsw?file=index.ts)

Rather than using `scan` (which will give you the current accumulated value on *each* of the 3 emissions) I would suggest [reduce](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/reduce), which will fire only once when the source completes.

```
import { of, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { reduce, expand, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

timer(1000).pipe(
  expand(() => of('a')),
  take(3),
  reduce((acc, val) => { acc.push(val); return acc; }, [])
).subscribe(val => console.log('Output:', val));
```

// Output: [0, a, a]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a very specific use case and there are multiple ways to do it.

#### Option 1: [`scan`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/scan) and [`filter`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/filter) operators

```js
timer(1000).pipe(
  expand(() => of('a')),
  take(3),
  scan((acc, curr) => {
    acc.push(curr);    // <-- push each notification to the array
    return acc;        
  }, []),              // <-- empty array `[]` as seed value 
  filter(values => values.length === 3)    // <-- emit only if notification length is 3
).subscribe(data => alert(data));
```

Note that the observable using `scan` operator is emitting 3 notifications: `[0]`, `[0, 'a']` and `[0, 'a', 'a']`. We explicitly restrict to emit only the last notification because we know it should be of length 3 (due to `take(3)`).

#### Option 2: [`scan`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/scan) and [`takeLast`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/takeLast) operators

```js
timer(1000).pipe(
  expand(() => of('a')),
  take(3),
  scan((acc, curr) => {
    acc.push(curr);    // <-- push each notification to the array
    return acc;        
  }, []),              // <-- empty array `[]` as seed value 
  takeLast(1)          // <-- emit the last 1 notification
).subscribe(data => alert(data));
```

#### Option 3: [`scan`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/scan) and [`last`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/last) operators

```js
timer(1000).pipe(
  expand(() => of('a')),
  take(3),
  scan((acc, curr) => {
    acc.push(curr);    // <-- push each notification to the array
    return acc;        
  }, []),              // <-- empty array `[]` as seed value 
  last()               // <-- emit the last notification
).subscribe(data => alert(data));
```

`last` operator offers one more option similar to `filter` operator. You could pass a predicate and the notification will only be emitted if it satisfies the predicate.

```js
timer(1000).pipe(
  expand(() => of('a')),
  take(3),
  scan((acc, curr) => {
    acc.push(curr);    // <-- push each notification to the array
    return acc;        
  }, []),              // <-- empty array `[]` as seed value 
  last((values) => values.includes('a'))     // <-- emit only if array contains 'a'
).subscribe(data => alert(data));
```

#### Option 4: [`reduce`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/reduce) operator

Refer the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62438552/6513921) from @NathanBeck.

#### Update

#### Option 5: [`toArray`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/toArray) operator

Possibly the quickest solution would be to use `toArray()` operator.

```js
timer(1000).pipe(
  expand(() => of('a')),
  take(3),
  toArray()
).subscribe(data => alert(data));
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer -- that scan() using `[]` was the inspiration behind the `reduce` part of my answer.

Comment: @NathanBeck: TBH, I overlooked the `reduce()` and went straight to `scan()`. Your answer fits better actually. Infact, [`reduce()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/reduce.ts#L73) uses `scan()` internally.

Comment: After you had answered with the first option I was also trying to use Last() or takeLast(). For now, I think the Option 4: reduce operator is the best.

Comment: If my `expand` returns an `Observable<[]>` each time... how can I concatenate them into a single observable? Doing `toArray()`  returns `Observable<[][]>`